# BigQuery - Deleting rows from multiple tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Trying to delete rows from multiple tables in single query.
Trying something like below

```
DELETE from dataset1.tbl1,dataset2.tbl2 where col ='condition'
```

The above query does not work. Any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: each delete generally requires a separate query. You'll have to use dynamic SQL here.

Comment: Create different query or a script to do that.

Comment: you need separate queries separated by semicolon in a single script.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use scripting statements with temp functions and tables on bigquery. Here is a sample on how it will work out:

```
/* set working variables */
DECLARE id INT64;
DECLARE counter INT64 DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE query STRING;

/* build a function for your dynamic query build */
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DeleteColFromTable(table_name STRING, col_name STRING, val_col_name STRING) 
AS (format("DELETE FROM `%s` WHERE %s = %s; ", table_name,col_name,val_col_name));

/* build your temp table with the tables and conditions to match and delete */
CREATE TEMP TABLE vals_to_delete AS (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over() as id_query,query from
    (select DeleteColFromTable('my-project-id.my-data-set.Authors','Author','Henry II') as query
     union all
     select DeleteColFromTable('my-project-id.my-data-set.Books','Author','Henry II') as query
    )
    /*add as many queries as you want to delete*/
);

/*perform operation*/
set id= (Select MAX(id_query) FROM vals_to_delete);

while counter<=id do
    set query = (select query from vals_to_delete where id_query = counter);
    execute immediate (query);
    set counter = counter+1;
end while
```

Here are some useful links about this case:

- [Scripting Statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting):
  A description on how to handle variables, while and execute immediate.
- [Data Definition Language](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language):
  A document that contains table references available in bigquery.